# How not to call (spy) methods of static member (KafkaTemplate UT)

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have class

```
public **abstract** class BaseClass<K, V> implements SomeService {

    private KafkaTemplate<K, V> kafkaTemplate;

    @Override
    public void init(Map<String, Object> params) {
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<K, V> defaultKafkaProducerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(params);
        kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(defaultKafkaProducerFactory);
    }

    public void send(Message message) { 
        ProducerRecord<K, V> record = new ProducerRecord<>("topic", "key", someObject);
        RecordMetadata recordMetadata = kafkaTemplate.send(record).get().getRecordMetadata();
    }
}
```

My question is how to test this class, **the only thing I wanted is to check that kafkaTemplate.send happens at least 1 time**.

I don't want to use embedded Kafka with spring (too difficult for this test). How can initialize and spy and not really call methods of KafkaTemplate?

Comment: Create a `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` in your unit test. You can create a `MessageListener` on this Container with `. setupMessageListener(..)`. The `MessageListener` can either add the record(s) to a `LinkedBlockingQueue` which your unit test poll, or use a `CountDownLatch`. You can populate `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` with your required Kafka settings.

Comment: I don't want really send something. I need to check fact that method send was called, that is all. Unit Test.

Comment: Okay. This is unrelated to Kafka. You can use independency injection to test your method. You can use reflection to inject a mocked `KafkaTemplate`. You can use frameworks such as `Mockito` to make mocking easier. `Mockito` offers `verify(..)` to check methods are called with given arguments. http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.19.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verify(T)